# What does "warning C4987: nonstandard extension used: 'throw (...)'" mean?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, atl, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to compile a VC++ project and it complains about this error

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlalloc.h(517): warning C4987: nonstandard extension used: 'throw (...)'
```

and the line that it points to is

```
_Ret_opt_bytecap_x_(nElements * sizeof(T)) T* Allocate(_In_ size_t nElements) throw( ... )
    {
        return( AllocateBytes( ::ATL::AtlMultiplyThrow(nElements,sizeof( T )) ) );
    }
```

Comment: What is `throw( ... )` supposed to mean? It's not standard, as the compiler says

Comment: It means you're using a language extension...

Comment: Is it a C project or a C++ project? Because in C, `try`, `catch` or `throw` is not part of the language standard, whereas in C++ it is.

Comment: Note that it's a **warning**, not an **error**. But it is odd that Microsoft's own code doesn't get along with their compiler.

Comment: It is one of many warnings you'll get when you compile with /Wall.  Maybe you disabled extensions entirely with /Za, although you don't usually get very far with that.  Getting a warning when code uses non-standard extension is, well, what warnings are for.  The whole exception specification debacle is at the core of this, a problem that won't go away for a while.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the `throw(...)` exception specification is a non-standard extension (a non-answer if there ever was one...), that is, the C++ standard does not define a meaning for this piece of code. In Visual Studio it means that the function may throw any exceptions.

If it were your own code, you could fix the warning by simply removing the exception specification (well, for C++ exceptions, anyway; I don't know how that would affect Microsoft's structured exception handling).

Comment: SEH won't be affected in any way. The only thing that affects it (more strictly - automatic exception handling code that calls destructors of local variables upon exception) - is the global exception handling flag.